# Запуск View из Tab Bar Controlller

Tags: ios, swift

Доброго времени суток. Есть сложность из настройкой Tab Bar Controller, суть проблемы в том что при старте программы какая из нескольких view будет запущена, определяется автоматически(алгоритм выбора есть), а вот как реализовать простой запуск view, без каких либо нажатий неизвестно.

Comment: можно подробнее, что именно надо получить.

Comment: надо получить программу, которая при разных обстоятельствах, запускает другое View

Comment: в смысле меняет выбранный tabbarview у UITabBarController?

Comment: Есть TavBarController, есть несколько view, значки которых находятся на TabBar-e, по дефолту программа стартует на первой вкладке, мне же нужно настроить этот "дефолт"

Comment: У UITabBarController есть два метода `selectedViewController` и `selectedIndex`. вызывайте какой больше нравится сразу на запуске приложения либо во `viewDidLoad` первого контроллера.

Comment: ну как, есть какие то успехи?

Answer (score 1):

Для программного переключения между view в таб бар контроллере есть два метода selectedViewController и selectedIndex:

можно либо указать какой контроллер должен стать активным (при этом если передать контроллер, который не входит в массив контроллеров данного таб бар, ничего не произойдет)

```
tabbar.selectedViewController = myViewController
```

либо указать индекс нового контроллера

```
 tabbar.selectedIndex = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Внутри  метода `viewWillApper` напиши

```
self.selectedViewController = self.viewControllers![newIndex] as! UIViewController
```

newIndex - индекс того контроллера, который ты хочешь, чтобы появлялся первым